# How to change the timezone for my android application

Tags: android, timezone, android-timepicker

I am displaying the current time (device time) in my application. I would like to change the timezone and would like to display the time of changed timezone in the application.

and the code is like this..

```
Calendar mCalendar; 
public CustomDate(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initClock(context);
 }

private void initClock(Context context) {

    if (mCalendar == null) {            
          mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    }
    else
    {     
         mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+04:00"));  
         mCalendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Venezuela")); 
    }
    mFormatChangeObserver = new FormatChangeObserver();
    getContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
            Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, mFormatChangeObserver);   
}
```

I would like to return the changed timezone time in that mCalendar. I am not getting the value, same time is displaying.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change system's default time zone, then use [setTimeZone()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29) of AlarmManager.